# How to clean my OpenSSL installation

Tags: python, compiling, openssl, tls

I use Ubuntu 18.04. It was shipped with OpenSSL 1.1.0g 
. I tried to link manually compiled Python to a manually compiled OpenSSL1.1.1a but things does not seem to work well. When I now run Python it is automatically linked to OpenSSL1.1.1a. I want to revert this. I want to restore OpenSSL1.1.0g as the default library for my system and my system's installed python. When I check my system's OpenSSL version I get:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018)
```

When I check:

```
whereis openssl
```

I get:

```
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/local/openssl /usr/local/openssl/bin/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

How can I remove OpenSSL 1.1.1a and just leave the system's OpenSSL 1.1.0g? How can I make Python linked to OpenSSL 1.1.0g? Any Python is linked to OpenSSL 1.1.1a now.

**EDIT:**

The command I used to compile python and openssl is similar to (except different versions):

```
# new openssl install
curl https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz | tar xz && cd openssl-1.0.2g && ./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/ && make && make install

# Python install script
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib/"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/openssl"
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential checkinstall -y
apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev -y
cd /home/web/
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tgz | tar xzf Python-2.7.11.tgz && cd Python-2.7.11 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ 
make altinstall
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to uninstall the manually compiled version of OpenSSL 1.1.1a. Assuming you've kept the build directory, this is as simple as running `make uninstall` in that folder. After successfully completing that, you need to reinstall the Ubuntu package using `apt-get install --reinstall openssl`.

Comment: Can you plz clarify what do you mean by `build directory`? Is it the directory of the source code?

Comment: I edited my question. Can you specify where shall I run the make uninstall as it is not clear to me what do you mean by build directory.

Comment: Your third line from the bottom says `cd Python-2.7.11`, followed by `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` and `make altinstall`. This means that the last two commands were executed in that directory. Run `make uninstall` in the same directory (`Python-2.7.11`).

Comment: Legend! I spent days trying to fix this and tried various suggestions until I found your solution. Thanks so much!